# Data studio how to make a normal table from Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata, looker-studio

I have a Bigquery view, when I make a query on this view (Cloud console):

```
SELECT CREATED_ON, ACCOUNT_DN FROM dataset.BILLING_HISTORY where CREATED_ON = '2021-07-27T10:28:04Z';
```

I got the result:

```
[{
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}, {
  "CREATED_ON": "2021-07-27T10:28:04Z",
  "ACCOUNT_DN": "f23f8cba-ef18-4245-95a0-cce3e671466c"
}]
```

Around 46 records (all CREATED_ON are the same, some ACCOUNT_DN are duplicated, this is my expectation result)

Now I want to make a table on Data studio (reflect this view). My table setup and result:

[image: Data studio setup]

As you can see, some ACCOUNT_DN are duplicated, this is normal, but all CREATED_ON are unique that is not my expectation. I just want to make a data studio table that cloned exactly from my Bigquery view (no need to count, group by, etc), but I don't know why the CREATED_ON get distinct. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article):

> **Tables in Data Studio**
>
> Tables in Data Studio ***automatically group your
> data***. ***Each row in the table displays the unique combination of all the
> dimensions included in the table definition***. Each metric in the table
> is aggregated according to the aggregation type for that metric (sum,
> average, count, etc.).

Workaround. You can add an additional unique column, for instance **RowNumber**:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) AS RN, 
        CREATED_ON,
        ACCOUNT_DN
FROM    dataset.BILLING_HISTORY
```